# pgrep wget: what is the details of process id?

Tags: wget, pgrep

when typing `pgrep wget`, it show process id `10144`

but how to know what is the details of this process id

Comment: What details do you want to know ?

Comment: All I want is: what is the command for the id. because I use wget frequently, sometime I forgot an id is belong to which command

Answer (score 5):

Use the `-f` and `-l` parameter:

```
pgrep -fl wget
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `ps` command:

```
ps ax | grep wget | grep -v grep
```